# How to get my recent photos from Instagram?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I read the instargam API and searched the code in google but not getting any exact solution for my requirement. I want to show my recent photos in my website like Facebook plugin. My images look like -

[image]

I tried following URL but I am getting error. Can you check -

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent?access_token=fb2e77d.47a0479900504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d
```

And

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/user-id/media/recent/?access_token=72020554b1884a9691352d4cd9759951
```

Please suggest me how to show my recent photos looks like above screenshot?

*Edit :* I have `Client ID` and `Client Secreat`. Let me know which one is `Access Token`?

Comment: The Instagram API returns a JSON object - you need to iterate over it to get the image IDs and then create the layout yourself.  There is no display formatting in the JSON, other than image size options.  Your second URL is the correct end point to get your own images, but you need your user ID (number) and a correct access token (which will be in the format of the one in your first URL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used this `API` Please check. I am sure this will helps to you.

```
<?php
$access_token = 'YOUR_3rd_PARTY_ACCESS_TOKEN';
$user_id = 'INSTAGRAM_USER_ID';
$json_profile = file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$user_id}/?access_token={$access_token}");
$json = file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$user_id}/media/recent/?access_token=" . $access_token . "&count=9");
$a_json_profile = json_decode($json_profile, true);
$a_json = json_decode($json, true);
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($json2);
//echo "</pre>"; exit;
$i = 0;
foreach ($a_json['data'] as $key => $value) {
    //if ($i < 9) {
    $a_images[$i]['link'] = $value['link'];
    $a_images[$i]['url'] = $value['images']['thumbnail']['url'];
    //$a_images[$value['id']]['caption'] = $value['caption']['text'];

    $i++;
    //}
}
shuffle($a_images);
$finalData = array('info'=>$a_json_profile, 'images'=>$a_images);
echo json_encode($finalData);
exit;
```

Comment: sadly not working anymore (2022).

Answer (score 3):

**fb2e77d.47a0479900504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d** -> this is the instagram example you need obtain your own ACCESS TOKEN.

Replace the values in the array.

> 'client_id' ;      'client_secret';     'redirect_uri'    and 'code'

**client_id**: your client id
**client_secret**: your client secret 
**grant_type**: authorization_code is currently the only supported value
**redirect_uri**: the redirect_uri you used in the authorization request. Note: this has to be the same value as in the authorization request.
**code:** the exact code you received during the authorization step.

Read the oficial document([Instagram Dev.](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/)
) **Step One**: Direct your user to our authorization URL and **Step Two**: Receive the redirect from Instagram (here you obtain CODE).

```
$apiData = array(
  'client_id'       => $client_id,
  'client_secret'   => $client_secret,
  'grant_type'      => 'authorization_code',
  'redirect_uri'    => $redirect_uri,
  'code'            => $code
);

$apiHost = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiHost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($apiData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($apiData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$jsonData = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($jsonData);
$user = @json_decode($jsonData); 


print_r($user);
```

You can check the oficial page.
[Instagram Dev.](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/)

Comment: This snippet is to request for an access_token and not to get the feed itself.